# BufferedImage to BMP in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, bmp

I have a BufferedImage object and I want to encode it to the BMP format and save it to disk.

How do I do this?

In `JPEG` it's ok:

```
BufferedImage img; //here is an image ready to be recorded into the hard disk
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("image.jpg");

JPEGImageEncoder jencoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fout);
JPEGEncodeParam enParam = jencoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(img);

enParam.setQuality(1.0F, true);
jencoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(enParam);
jencoder.encode(img);

fout.close();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) -

```
ImageIO.write(img, "BMP", new File("filename.bmp"))
```

Comment: Make sure that `BufferedImage` is `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` and not  `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should do:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", new File("filename.bmp"));
```

where image is the BufferedImage you want to encode.

Comment: Make sure that `BufferedImage` is `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` and not  `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`