# Java : BufferedImage to Bitmap format

Tags: java, bitmap, bufferedimage

I have a program in which i capture the screen using the code :

```
robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
```

Now i want to convert this BufferedImage into Bitmap format and return it through a function for some other need, Not save it in a file. Any help please??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961687/bufferedimage-to-bmp-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a look at [`ImageIO.write`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29).

- [The Java Tutorials: Writing/Saving an Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

If you want the result in the form of a `byte[]` array, you should use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(yourImage, "bmp", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

Comment: Well I had already viewed that class but it writes into a file Stream but i dont want to write it into a file i want to convert it into bitmap format in the memory itself and return it through a funtion.

Comment: Thank you i think that may help!!

Answer (score 2):

When you say "into Bitmap format" you then mean the data (as in a byte array)? If that's the case, then you can use `ImageIO.write` (like suggested above).
If you don't want to save it to a file, but just want to get the data, can you use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` like this:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "BMP", out);
byte[] result = out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the image types available for write in the J2SE (ex. JAI), see [`ImageIO.getWriterFileSuffixes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getWriterFileSuffixes%28%29):

### E.G.

```
class ShowJavaImageTypes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] imageTypes =
            javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriterFileSuffixes();
        for (String imageType : imageTypes) {
            System.out.println(imageType);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

For this Sun Java 6 JRE on Windows 7.

```
bmp
jpg
wbmp
jpeg
png
gif
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

See similar `ImageIO` methods for MIME types, formats, and the corresponding readers.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromBufferedImage(BufferedImage image)
{
     return redResult.getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: no such `BufferedImage::getBitmap()`  in my IDE here

Comment: Oh... yeah, that's right. Can you tell me your use case?