# How to convert java.awt.Image in Bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, bufferedimage

I am trying to convert `BufferedImage` into bitmap to set bitmap in `ImageView` but I am getting an error. Is there any way to set `java.awt.Image` in `ImageView`?

```
            BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = null;
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byt);


            try {
                bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);               
                Image ima = bImageFromConvert;

                Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.;

            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: check on stackoverflow thereare many similar examples.

Comment: I want to convert `BufferedImage` into `Bitmap`. or is there any way to set `java.awt.Image` in `ImageView`?

Comment: @Raghunandan I already did that. I can't find proper solution

Comment: This seems similar I think,, check that 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961687/bufferedimage-to-bmp-in-java

Comment: yeah I checked that but I don't want to save that image, I want to show the bitmap in 'ImageView'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to set `java.awt.Image` in `ImageView`?

Short answer: No.

You can't use `Image`, `BufferedImage` (`java.awt` package) or `ImageIO` (`javax.imageio` package) from Android. So I'm guessing the error you see is related to that.

Maybe if you try to ask how to achieve your goal, rather than this specific implementation issue, maybe we could help you further. :-)